# stop and start mysql service using aspx .net page

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database

Currently we are getting some time issue with MySQL Server

> too many connections.

We need to create an `aspx` page to run during too many connection to restart MySQL or application pool. Is it possible?

Comment: Why dont you increase your max connections limit? What you are trying to do is no solution

Comment: Are you sure your connections are getting closed when you're done with them? Do you use `using` statements around your connections? Or do you use try/catch/finally with a `.Close()` statement in the finally block? Seems like this might be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Can you share with us your code where you open and close the connection.

Comment: I have increased connections but the code having a lots of connections like 400 on a single hit also .Close() method used in code.  but some time we get too many connections on test url which is causing to down live site also as its running MySQL single instance (Service).

So in case of we got error MySQL Too Many Connection" we can use a separate url to recycle application pool or MySQL Instance..

Comment: con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

Comment: @RameshChand Simply calling close and dispose isn't enough. Please read my comment and address the points I raised.

Comment: Thanks Mason for your query ! But i have to create a page to recycle app pool or restart mysql Service to avoid any downtime due to developers mistake when they did.

Comment: You can't just restart your SQL Server in a production environment (especially not manually!). Get to the root of the problem and fix that instead.